# how to use if else condition in angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi i am newly to Angular JS,
I want Convert  AM/PM format in JavaScript for Example ( 25-10-2013 18:30 to  25-10-2013 6:30 PM   )
controller file

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.AvailableSlots.length; i++) 
    $scope.AvailableSlots[i].AppointmentDate  = Date.parse(moment($scope.AvailableSlots[i].F).format('MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm')) ; 
}

<div>
    <button class="btn btn-danger"  ng-click="cancelAppointment(appointment)">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

here  Cancel Button should appear only if the Appointment date is future date. Otherwise, the cancel button should be hidden.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this using the `ng-show="isFutureDay"` attribute.

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" 
        ng-show="isFutureDay" 
        ng-click="cancelAppointment(appointment)">Cancel</button>
```

where `isFutureDay` would be a boolean variable in the scope, which indicates if the appointment day is a future day or not. If it is a future day, `isFutureDay===true`, then the button will be visible. Otherwise, it will be invisible.

For further documentation about `ng-show`, please have a look [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow).

Answer (score 0):

If you use data binding, you can do it using filters, such as:

```
{{ AvailableSlots[0].AppointmentDate | date:'MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a' }}
```

The [0] is for simplicity's sake.

As for the Cancel button, you can use the "ng-show" attribute, such as:

```
ng-show="(AppointmentDate - today's date) > 0"
```

Inside the button, so it's shown only if that condition is true.

Answer (score 0):

first create a boolean in js for isFuture

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.AvailableSlots.length; i++) 
    $scope.AvailableSlots[i].AppointmentDate  = Date.parse(moment($scope.AvailableSlots[i].F).format('MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm')) ; 
    $scope.AvailableSlots[i].IsFuture  = moment().isBefore($scope.AvailableSlots[i].AppointmentDate) ; 
}
```

and then in js

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" ng-show="appointment.IsFuture" ng-click="cancelAppointment(appointment)">Cancel</button>
```

Comment: did the answer helped